# How to add keybindings in vscode neovim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

I want to add `space+w` to write file in vscode neovim in normal mode. I followed the documentation and added the keybinding like this :

```json
  {
    "command": "workbench.action.files.save",
    "key": "Space+w",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.mode != insert"
```

But its not working while,

```json
{
    "command": "vscode-neovim.compositeEscape1",
    "key": "j",
    "when": "neovim.mode == insert && editorTextFocus",
    "args": "j"
  },
```

this is working perfectly fine.